# I have function for writing to the screen in pygame but it doesnt work

Tags: python, pygame

I write project in pygame and now I'm writing the Login part.
I wrote a function that print one char to the screen by spesific place but it doesn't work and I don't know why.

here my code: the function called print_char_by_place(char, row, col) and I use it in the end of the code.

```
import pygame
import os




def if_button_pressed(left_col, right_col, high_row, low_row, mouse):
    if mouse[0]>=left_col and mouse[0]<=right_col and mouse[1]>=high_row and          mouse[1]<=low_row:
        return True
    return  False

# get char that pressed in the keyboard and print it by place
def print_char_by_place(char, row, col):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 15)
    label = font.render(char, 1, black)
    screen.blit(label, (row, col))



pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 700))
done = True
login = True
user_name_p = False
password_p = False
username = ""
password = ""
row_u = 343
col_u = 260
while done:
    img = pygame.image.load("LOGIN.png")
    screen.blit(img,(0,0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if if_button_pressed(255,418,331,355,mouse):      # if the     username pressed
                username_p = True
                password_p = False

            if if_button_pressed(255,418,382,403,mouse):      # if the password pressed
                username_p = False
                password_p = True

            else:
                 user_name_p = False
                 password_p = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if user_name_p:
                char = str(event.key)
                username+=char
                print_char_by_place(char,row_u,col_u)   
                col_u+=2



        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = False
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that each character entered by the user is only rendered for a single frame. Once the next frame rolls around, the background image will be drawn over the top of it and you'll never see it again (if you were even able to notice it in the first place).

If you want the text to remain visible, you need to keep drawing it each frame. Probably you don't want to do this in the key-press detection code, which already has logic to extend the `username` variable. You should add some other code that will render `username` to the screen (and not only the frames when a key is pressed).

Answer (score 0):

```
name=""
if event.key>=97 and event.key<=122 and len(name)< 22 or event.key>=48 and event.key<=57 and len(name)< 22:
    name += str(pygame.key.name(event.key))
```

You can use this code to read each key press and add the string. This string you can convert to an image and print to screen each loop. If you need to erase the last character you simply do

```
if event.key == K_BACKSPACE:
    name = name[:-1]
```

Once the name is complete you can compare this string with tha actual usename or whatever to see if True or False.